# Where are the Articles of Harmony and Implements of Song quest mobs?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

I'm working on the Minstrel class quests, [Articles of Harmony](http://lotro.mmodb.com/quests/articles-of-harmony-1248.php) and [Implements of Song](http://lotro.mmodb.com/quests/implements-of-song-1249.php).

I need a [Goblin Badge of Rank](http://lotro.mmodb.com/items/goblin-badge-of-rank-1788.php), an [Ashen Gorthorog Horn](http://lotro.mmodb.com/items/ashen-gorthorog-horn-5986.php), a [Rune of Winged Dominance](http://lotro.mmodb.com/items/rune-of-winged-dominance-1829.php), and an [Emblem of Ritual](http://lotro.mmodb.com/items/emblem-of-ritual-7349.php).

mmodb.com says they're dropped by [Akrur](http://lotro.mmodb.com/bestiary/akrur-3143.php), [Tarlug](http://lotro.mmodb.com/bestiary/tarlug-2847.php), [Mormoz](http://lotro.mmodb.com/bestiary/mormoz-2846.php), and [Morthrang](http://lotro.mmodb.com/bestiary/morthrang-3144.php), respectively, but I don't know where specifically those 4 mobs are located. Where are they, or where are other mobs drop the quest items?

Also, it looks like those mobs have between 30k and 38k each, so I'm guessing I'm not going to be able to solo them, despite the quests not even being marked small group. Is this assumption correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are raid bosses, I believe, for level 50 content 24-man raids.

You can also buy those items off of Skirmish Vendors (Curiousity, I *think*), which was the easiest way for me. They're expensive, but worth it.

Answer (score 2):

They drop from mobs/bosses in Carn Dum, a lvl 50 6-man instance.  Other than that you can bet them from skrimish vendors as Trevel mentioned.